# Javascript var name counting variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following bit of code:

```
function finalCheck(theForm) {
var z = 0;
for(var i=0;i<15;i++){
    var _i = theForm.elements[i].value;
    if(_i == ""){
        theForm.elements[i].style.background = '#FFD6D6';
        z = 1;
    }
}
if(z == 1){
    alert("Please correct the fields highlighted in red");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

What I was attempting to do was set the name of `var _i` to `var _` and then the index that the counting variable was currently on. For example, `_1 _2 _3` etc. Any way to do this?

Comment: The code looks like it will probably work (at a glance), but the question you're asking makes no sense, sorry :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I see no reason to do something like this. These variables seem to be temporarily only anyway and you only need to have access to one value at the time. So no need to create a new variable in each iteration.

Comment: Uh, what do you mean? What are you trying to achieve? I don't see _ anywhere.

Comment: To refrence the variables outside of the `for()` loop.

Comment: @Jason: Then use an array. Using dynamic variable names is a horrible idea in most cases.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't create dynamic variable names in JavaScript. You should push the values into an array.

Answer (score 1):

So I under stand what you are trying to do, and your solution is to use `eval`

```
eval("var _" + i + "= theForm.elements[i].value;");
```

Anyways your code doesn't need any dynamic generation of variable names as `var _i` is a local variable.
I hope you are asking this question for learning purpose.